# How can I breakup a large init (due to a large quantity of computations), for better readability?

Tags: swift, initialization

I have a class, with say 100 properties (exaggeration).
Most of these properties must be computed, based off of user preferences.

These properties will not change after the initialization, which is why I would like to run the computations once at the beginning, and set the results into `let` properties

Users can set tens of preferences, and depending on the combination of preferences set, the properties here will change when I initialize an object.

```
let prop1:String
let prop2:String
...
let prop100:String

init(maybeRelevantArg:Int, maybeRelevantArg2:String) {
    var proposedProp1 = ""
    //20 lines of logic to compute proposedProp1, referencing preferences and maybeRelevantArgs
    self.prop1 = proposedProp1

    var proposedProp2 = ""
    //20 lines of logic to compute proposedProp2, referencing preferences and maybeRelevantArgs
    self.prop2 = proposedProp2
}
```

You get the point, at this point my `init` will be hundreds of lines long, basically unreadable.

I would like to separate these chunks of logic out into separate methods, something like:

```
init(maybeRelevantArg:Int, maybeRelevantArg2:String) {
    self.computeAndSetProp1(relevantArg:maybeRelevantArg1)
    self.computeAndSetProp2(relevantArg:maybeRelevantArg2)
}

func computeAndSetProp1(relevantArg:String) {
    var proposedProp1 = ""
    //20 lines of logic to compute proposedProp1, referencing preferences and relevantArgs
    self.prop1 = proposedProp1
}
```

This way the `init` is much more readible, and it should be easier to debug and maintain.

The issue is that obviously the compiler won't be happy that my `init` method is not explicitly initializing these properties, and I get something akin to:

> 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized

and also, inside of `computeAndSetProp1()`, I will get this error:

> cannot assign to property: 'prop1' is a 'let' constant

**Is there a way to split up this large init?**

Comment: Use static factory methods to break down the init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `computeAndSetProp1()` function be a free function (that is, not part of any class), like this:

```
func computeAndSetProp1(relevantArg: String) -> String {
    var proposedProp1 = ""
    //20 lines of logic to compute proposedProp1, referencing preferences and relevantArgs
    return proposedProp1;
}

class someClass: NSObject {
    let prop1 : String
    let prop2 : String
    override init() {
        prop1 =  computeAndSetProp1(relevantArg: "x")
        //...etc.
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend seeing if you can generalize the `computeAndSetProp*` functions to reduce the amount of code. You can always post the code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get more ideas about how to simplify the code.

Comment: oh d'oh, this is one of things where I was overthinking it.  For some reason my mind was telling me to set the properties inside of the outside methods... but I can just return values and set directly in the `init`, as you are doing in your example

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to store the init parameters in private let properties, and have the computation in a computed var. You could also to a private(set) lazy var if you want the computation logic to happen just once.

Other idea could be to break apart the class into multiple classes/structs with related properties, and then have the existing class hold on to these smaller classes/structs.